# jQuery AJAX post array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this JavaScript array:

```
testarr = new Array();
testarr[0] = new Array();
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"] = "White";
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"] = new Array();
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"]["#FFFFFA"] = "A";
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"]["#FFFFFB"] = "B";

testarr[0]["#000000"] = "Black";
testarr[0]["#000000"] = new Array();
testarr[0]["#000000"]["#000001"] = "A1";
testarr[0]["#000000"]["#000002"] = "B1";
```

I use this jQuery AJAX post method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'backEndFile.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {cat:testarr},
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success === true) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
      } else {
        alert("NOT SUCCESS")
      }
    }
  });
```

my backEndFile.php

```
<?php
  var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

In backEndFile var dump prints: `array(0) {}` not found me post array.

**if I change me array keys from string to digits like this:**

```
testarr[0] = new Array();
testarr[0][0] = "White";
testarr[0][0] = new Array();
testarr[0][0][0] = "A";
testarr[0][0][1] = "B";

testarr[0][1] = "Black";
testarr[0][1] = new Array();
testarr[0][1][0] = "A1";
testarr[0][1][1] = "B1";
```

**then prints correctly**

Comment: Tip: Replace your `me` with `my`. It's unrelated, but it's worth it fixing them.

Comment: Try serializing your object to JSON, use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify): `data: JSON.stringify({cat:testarr})`. Currently jQquery might be seriliazing your object to url encoded form.

Comment: i try: data: JSON.stringify({cat:testarr}) doesn't get result..

Comment: Javascript arrays don't have string indices, you appear to require an array containing objects.  Also, you overwrite the value "Black" with new Array() on the next line.

Comment: To properly validate the JSON your are receiving in PHP try following: `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: @tpeczek — serializing an array with named keys to JSON will have the same problem as serializing it to form data hash.

Comment: @Quentin - of course, but he is trying to get JSON so I'm leading him into direction of getting JSON. Handling array of objects and entire objects try he wants to achieve is a separate thing.

Comment: @tpeczek — You were the first person to mention JSON as far as the *request* format was concerned.

Comment: @Quentin - You are right, I got confused by JSON tag attached to this question. My bad.

Comment: work with: `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are designed for holding data with *sequential*, *numeric* key names.

When jQuery serialises them for an Ajax request, it will only include the numeric keys (because it is an array, so why would you put named keys on it?).

If you want to have *named* keys, then use an `Object`, not an `Array`.

```
testarr = new Array();
testarr[0] = new Object();
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"] = "White";
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"] = new Object();
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"]["#FFFFFA"] = "A";
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"]["#FFFFFB"] = "B";

testarr[0]["#000000"] = "Black";
testarr[0]["#000000"] = new Object();
testarr[0]["#000000"]["#000001"] = "A1";
testarr[0]["#000000"]["#000002"] = "B1";
```

Note that you are overwriting your White and Black values with arrays. You probably don't want to do that.

(In general, you should also prefer the literal syntax (`[]`/`{}`) to the constructor syntax (`new Array`/`new Object`)).

```
testarr = [];
testarr[0] = {};
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"] = "White";
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"] = {};
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"]["#FFFFFA"] = "A";
testarr[0]["#FFFFFF"]["#FFFFFB"] = "B";

testarr[0]["#000000"] = "Black";
testarr[0]["#000000"] = {};
testarr[0]["#000000"]["#000001"] = "A1";
testarr[0]["#000000"]["#000002"] = "B1";
```

But then you can go the whole hog and just use literal syntax throughout:

```
testarr = [
        {
                "#FFFFFF": {
                        "#FFFFFA": "A",
                        "#FFFFFB": "B"
                },
                "#000000": {
                        "#000001": "A1",
                        "#000002": "B1"
                }
        }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
testarr = {}
testarr[0] = {}
testarr[0]["white"] = {}
testarr[0]["white"]["#FFFFFA"] = "A";
testarr[0]["white"]["#FFFFFB"] = "B";

testarr[0]["black"] = {}
testarr[0]["black"]["#000001"] = "A1";
testarr[0]["black"]["#000002"] = "B1";

console.log(testarr[0].white);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more reasonable way of generating your structure:

```
var testarr = [{
  "#FFFFFF": {
    "#FFFFFA": "A", 
    "#FFFFFB": "B"
  },
  "#000000": {
    "#000001": "A1",
    "#000002": "B1"
  }
}];

console.log(testarr[0]["#000000"]["#000001"]); // result "A1"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try decoding your data on your PHP side.

```
json_decode(YOURDATA);
```

or just like @tpeczek commented, try
`JSON.stringify({cat:testarr})` when posting it.

Comment: i try it doesn't work.. already get result empty array: `array(0) {}`